# Export explicit Jacoco it report to sonarqube 6.7

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

I'm not able to see the Integration Tests in new sonarqube 6.7 version, here is what I'm doing,

- Run Sonarqube task with Gradle to generate the report along with code coverage.
- Here, Sonarqube is by default invoking test task and using the test.exec file from build/jacoco generated by Jacoco plugin.
- However, I've a task depends on the test task to place an integrationTest.exec report in the build/jacoco as the integrations tests are run outside build(for some reason)
- Though I place the integrationTest.exec file explicitly while Sonarqube execution it is still not considering the report and due to which I do not see any change in the coverage computed also I do not see Integration Tests section under coverage like I see Unit Tests.

Firstly, I would like to understand that whether is it feasible to export the integration tests result like I did above or not?

Second, is the latest Sonarqube having the capability to show integration tests report in the coverage section?

Your comments would help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to use integration-tests to enhance the code coverage?

Comment: @JeroenHeier yes! I've integrationTest.exec generated for the same? and wanted to combine that with existing coverage report in sonar and display in the dashboard.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project) does not help?

Comment: I tried this but no luck, then I had set sonar.jacoco.itReportPath property to sonar and point to the IT reports and it worked. BTW I'm using Gradle for the build.